# Authorize.net API integration "invalid child element 'transactionSettings' in namespace" when charging payment profile

Tags: php, payment-gateway, authorize.net

Im integrating with authorize.net and process credit card transactions. I have the charge working fine for processing direct credit card payment :

```
$authnet_info = array(
        'createTransactionRequest' => array(
            'merchantAuthentication' => array(
                'name' => ######,
                'transactionKey' => #######
            ),
            
            'refId' => $data['reference_id'],
            'transactionRequest' => array(
                'transactionType' => 'authCaptureTransaction',
                'amount' => $data['charge_amount'],
                'payment' => array(
                    'creditCard' => array(
                        'cardNumber' => $data['cc_number'],
                        'expirationDate' => $data['cc_expiration'],
                        "cardCode" =>  $data['cvc']
                    )
                ),
                'customer' => array(
                    'type' => 'business',
                    'id' => $data['id_company']
                ),
                'billTo' => array(
                    "firstName" => $data['first_name'],
                    "lastName" => $data['last_name'],
                    'company' => $data['company_name'],
                    "address" => $data['address'],
                    "city" => $data['city'],
                    "state" => $data['state'],
                    "zip" => $data['zipcode']
                ),
                "transactionSettings" => array (
                    "setting" => array (
                        array(
                            "settingName" => "duplicateWindow",
                            "settingValue" => "5"
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

This works just fine however when i try to pass the same setting

```
             "transactionSettings" => array (
                    "setting" => array (
                        array(
                            "settingName" => "duplicateWindow",
                            "settingValue" => "5"
                        )
                    )
                )
```

For charging against a payment profile i get the following error:

```
(
                        [code] => E00003
                        [text] => The element 'transactionRequest' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd' has invalid child element 'transactionSettings' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'. List of possible elements expected: 'subsequentAuthInformation, otherTax, shipFrom, authorizationIndicatorType' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'.
                    )
```

Here is the post i am sending to authorize.net

```
{
"createTransactionRequest": {
    "merchantAuthentication": {
        "name": "######",
        "transactionKey": "##########"
    },
    "refId": "62",
    "transactionRequest": {
        "transactionType": "authCaptureTransaction",
        "amount": "25.00",
        "profile": {
            "customerProfileId": "1231231",
            "paymentProfile": {
                "paymentProfileId": "34534534534"
            }
        },
        "customer": {
            "type": "business",
            "id": 5
        },
        "processingOptions": {
            "isSubsequentAuth": "false"
        },
        "transactionSettings": {
            "setting": [{
                "settingName": "duplicateWindow",
                "settingValue": "5"
            }]
        }
    }
   }
 }
```

When i remove the transaction settings part of my post the charge goes through fine. Does anyone know where this setting needs to be placed? Their documentation clearly states in this location that i am placing however im not sure why it wont go through.

Edit: I tried the method mentioned below and received the same error:

```
{
"createTransactionRequest": {
    "merchantAuthentication": {
        "name": "#####",
        "transactionKey": "#######dfsd"
    },
    "refId": "62",
    "transactionRequest": {
        "transactionType": "authCaptureTransaction",
        "amount": "25.00",
        "profile": {
            "customerProfileId": "502810352",
            "paymentProfile": {
                "paymentProfileId": "511258154"
            }
        },
        "customer": {
            "type": "business",
            "id": 5
        },
        "processingOptions": {
            "isSubsequentAuth": "false"
        }
    },
    "transactionSettings": {
        "setting": [{
            "settingName": "duplicateWindow",
            "settingValue": "5"
        }]
    }
}
}
```

EDIT: i answered the question apparently i had a extra setting within the request that doesnt need to be present

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i figured out the issue for anyone else facing the same problem. The issue seemed to be the

```
"processingOptions": {
        "isSubsequentAuth": "false"
    }
```

setting within the request. I guess it not valid with the transactionsetting being present.

I ended up passing the following request and it worked fine

```
{
"createTransactionRequest": {
    "merchantAuthentication": {
        "name": "#####",
        "transactionKey": "######"
    },
    "refId": "62",
    "transactionRequest": {
        "transactionType": "authCaptureTransaction",
        "amount": "25.00",
        "profile": {
            "customerProfileId": "sdfsdf",
            "paymentProfile": {
                "paymentProfileId": "51sdfsdf1258154"
            }
        },
        "customer": {
            "type": "business",
            "id": 5
        },
        "transactionSettings": {
            "setting": [{
                "settingName": "duplicateWindow",
                "settingValue": "5"
            }]
        }
    }
}
 }
```